# How I can force scheme to return #f explicitly instead of just void?

Tags: scheme, return-value

```
(define every-aux
  (lambda(status predicate lst)
    (cond((null? lst) status)
         ((cond((equal? (predicate (car lst)) #t)
                (set! status #t)
                (every-aux status predicate (cdr lst)))
               (else (set! status #f) status))))))
```

Above Procedure returns void if predicate does not match with every element in lst?

It does not have any problem is returning #t though if predicate matches every element of lst.

Changing the last line to

```
(else (set! status #f) status))))))
```

to

```
 (else (set! status "#f") status))))))
```

returns "#f" so procedure is correct.

How I can force scheme to return #f explicitly instead of just void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eli Barzilay

After some I deliberation I could see the solution. Thanks for the pointers.

```
(define every?
  (lambda (predicate list)
    (if(null? list) "Empty List not allowed."
       (every-aux? predicate list))))

(define every-aux?
  (lambda (predicate lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((equal? (predicate (car lst)) #t) (every-aux? predicate (cdr lst)))
          (else #f))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very messy:

- You have a `cond` inside another, but `cond` is intended for multiple tests/results.
- There is no reason to have that `status` modified -- Scheme uses call-by-value, so this is likely not doing whatever you think it does.
- Specifically, there is no reason to use `(else (set! status #f) status)` -- you could just return `#f` directly.
- The actual reason for your confusion is the weird `cond` nesting -- the second `cond` is actually used as a *test*, so if you make it (the inner `cond`) return `#f`, then the whole test of the outer `cond` is getting `#f`, which means that it (the outer `cond`) didn't get any true result, and resorts to returning an unspecified value (and if this is Racket, then that value is shown as `#<void>`).  So if you flatten the two `cond`s into one, your problem will go away.
- Finally, if you're having problems at such a level, then you should consider using some textbook to familiarize yourself with the language.  Specifically [HtDP](http://htdp.org/) is intended to give you an easy path into getting familiar with the syntax.